# Spinner Date Picker show Day Name

Tags: android

I need to make my spinner DatePicker show day name (DAY_OF_WEEK) instead of numbers (DAY_OF_MONTH)

Currently the Spinner shows the number of days in month (1,2,3 ... 30), But I want it to show days names too (Sunday, Monday, ...)

Here is how I call it:

```
final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener sessDay = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                              int dayOfMonth) {
            dateCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            dateCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            dateCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            pickDayBtn.setText(Q.DATE_FORMAT.format(dateCalendar.getTime()));
        }
    };

dayPickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(SessionsSettingsActivity.this, R.style.MySpinnerDatePickerStyle, sessDay, dateCalendar
            .get(Calendar.YEAR), dateCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            dateCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

And this is the style I use:

```
<style name="MySpinnerDatePickerStyle" parent="android:Theme.Material.Dialog">
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MySpinnerDatePicker</item>
</style>

<style name="MySpinnerDatePicker" parent="android:Widget.Material.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Currently the Spinner shows the number of days in month (1,2,3 ... 30), But I want it to show days names too (Sunday, Monday, ...).

Comment: Do you want to show the day name in Spinner itself or get the day name in `OnDateSetListener` ?

Comment: No, In the Spinner it self...

Answer (score 0):

You should change the date format to achieve it bro. Below is a sample code:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy");   
Log.e("New Date Format ", String.valueOf(dateFormat.format(newDate.getTime())) + "");    
// Shows  "Saturday, August 19, 2017"
```

Upon changing the date format you may `override` your `spinner` the way you like.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to override the Spinner with DateFormat?